# JavaScript - RNG min, average, max need some help in connecting results

Tags: javascript

This is a assignment to be run on jsfiddle so it has a split html and javascript code. html is given. The task is to make it work with the given html. I did as much as I could with my limited knowledge in javascript. I pretty much understand what I am missing in this code, I just don't know how to write it. I have nothing connecting the results with the randomizer. Can someone tell me how I would do it? I checked out other threads regarding min-average-max, but I don't think the way they are doing it would work for mine.

##html code

```
`<h2>Problem #4: Data Simulation</h2>
<button onclick="runSimulation()">Run Simulation</button><br>
Largest number: <input type="text" id="max" disabled><br>
Smallest number: <input type="text" id="min" disabled><br>
Average: <input type="text" id="average" disabled><br>`
```

##javascript code

```
const LOWER_BOUND = 10000;
const UPPER_BOUND = 60000;

function runSimulation() {

    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;


document.querySelector("#max").value = max;
document.querySelector("#min").value = min;
document.querySelector("#average").value = average;

}
```

Comment: Just remove `return` from the function, and define also `average`, then store the random number into a variable, and multiply the other values with it, or how ever the random should be used.

Comment: just put the return statement at end  of the function

Comment: Where do you define `min` and `max`?

Comment: @Teemu I think the Kevin has declared `min` ,`max` and `average` as global  variable !

Comment: So I thought I put a comment as I input my edited code but I guess I did it wrong. I adjusted my code using the example from Sinan but... all I get is NaN.

Comment: Can someone look at my edited code to see if I should change something?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include the answer, accepting an answer is fine.

Comment: oh I didn't know, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning from the function, your DOM manipulation never works. Here is a similar working example:

```js
const LOWER_BOUND = 10000;
const UPPER_BOUND = 60000;

function runSimulation(){
   const [num1, num2] = [
   Math.floor(Math.random() * (UPPER_BOUND - LOWER_BOUND) + LOWER_BOUND),
   Math.floor(Math.random() * (UPPER_BOUND - LOWER_BOUND) + LOWER_BOUND)
   ]
   
   const max = Math.max(num1, num2), min = Math.min(num1, num2)
   const average = (max + min) / 2
   document.querySelector("#max").value = max;
   document.querySelector("#min").value = min;
   document.querySelector("#average").value = average;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h2>Problem #4: Data Simulation</h2>
<button onclick="runSimulation()">Run Simulation</button><br>
Largest number: <input type="text" id="max" disabled><br>
Smallest number: <input type="text" id="min" disabled><br>
Average: <input type="text" id="average" disabled><br>
</body>
```

Comment: The reason why I put `const LOWER_BOUND = 10000;
const UPPER_BOUND = 60000;` is due to the problem has to be within the boundary of 10000 and 60000.

Comment: This is a sample use case where you can fill out values in your html using a function. If you have other questions, please include it in the question or ask another one :) I don't know why you gave that information.

Comment: You can use the code `Math.random() * (UPPER_BOUND - LOWER_BOUND) + LOWER_BOUND;` to generate the numbers between your LOWER_BOUND, UPPER_BOUND

Comment: OP added a return statement, and I didn't remove it because it doesn't block the intended behavior.

Comment: I am new to javascript I didn't know that you didn't need a return. How would you recommend I end the code

Comment: You don't need to specify something to _end the code_ Function will exit the scope once there is no more lines to execute :)

Comment: Edited the answer with your bounds, please check.